# Difference between .so file and java library in ffmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg, cmake, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

Is there any difference between using ffmpeg with .so file(ndk,.cpp) or simply by using ffmpeg library(example: com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmeg). I see my collegues apps sell 10rs by using these libraries vs with app on cpp function call sells 1000rs+?

Implementation with java library:

```
FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
try {
  // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
  ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {}

    @Override
    public void onProgress(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {}
  });
} catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
  // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
}
```

Comment: What you show here most likely needs an external `ffmpeg` binary and will not work if you want to process media streams in-application.

Comment: ok! i dont know much about this java library, but what makes the difference if we write cpp code with shared objects, cmake and execute the process by hard c functions instead of this java library usage

Comment: That is the hard way. Building native code for Android is no picnic.